# How do I Open chrome 113's memory saver using chromedriver?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

chrome 113 has a new memory saver feature, which I tried to turn on using the Chrome Driver to control Google's browser, but couldn't find. What should I do? I'm using php-webdriver

```
$chromeOptions = (new ChromeOptions())
            ->addArguments([
                '--window-size=1600,900'
            ])
            ->setExperimentalOption('prefs', [
                "memory-saver" => 1,
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find anywhere how to enable it so in my scripts I have been using this as a workaround in Test Startup after starting driver, it will go to settings and enable it in Python

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/?search=memory+saver')
driver.execute_script(
    'document.querySelector("body > settings-ui").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main").shadowRoot.querySelector('
    '"settings-basic-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#performanceSettingsSection > '
    'settings-performance-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#toggleButton").shadowRoot.querySelector('
    '"#control").shadowRoot.querySelector("#knob").click()')
```

Php Equivalent

```
$driver->get('chrome://settings/?search=memory+saver');
$script = 'document.querySelector("body > settings-ui").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main").shadowRoot.querySelector('
    .'"settings-basic-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#performanceSettingsSection > '
    .'settings-performance-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#toggleButton").shadowRoot.querySelector('
    .'"#control").shadowRoot.querySelector("#knob").click()';

$driver->executeScript($script);
```